# Как защитить дизайн сайта от копирования?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите, существует ли возможность защитить сайт от копирования?

Нужно не дать скопировать сам HTML, CSS, JS.

Я нашел много вариантов по защите текста, но что с защитой самого сайта (дизайна)?

Comment: Я думаю что это не возможно даже если минифицировать то всеравно можно назад возвратить есть кучу сервисов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К сожалению, это практически не возможно.

Исходный код веб страницы всегда можно просмотреть и скопировать. Даже если этот код зашифрован.

Comment: https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/xakep/blog/128741/ почитай на досуге

Comment: @Kirya, уже читал. Поэтому знаю о чём говорю.

Answer (score 1):

Можно минифицировать некоторые файлы.

От копирования это не защитит, но в таком коде невероятно сложно разобраться.

Так же такие файлы будут быстрее передаваться клиентам.

Comment: "в таком коде невероятно сложно разобраться". http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Приходилось. Сложно, но можно (с) ничего невероятного

Comment: @Maxim остыньте. :) Во-первых, вы в профессиональном сообществе, а не на базаре, так что рекомендую общаться спокойно и уважительно. Во-вторых вы с девушкой спорите. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 1):

Advanced HTML Encrypt and Password Protect - можете попробовать что-то такое. С помощью js превращает все в консоли разработчика в белиберду...